# how to delete django relation and rebuild model

Tags: django, python-3.x

ive made a mistake with my django and messed up my model

I want to delete it & then recreate it - how do I do that?

I get this when I try to migrate - i just want to drop it
relation "netshock_todo" already exists

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all of your migrations file except `__init__.py`
Then go to database and find migrations table, delete all row in migrations table. Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command